# Why Intellij Idea auto format java codes when it opened?

Tags: intellij-idea

Codes will be reformatted when opening a java file and I can't find where to set it right.

For example, the java file content is:

```
public TestBankTask(String taskName, String bankCode) {
    super(taskName, bankCode);
}
```

But when it opening in the Intellij Idea Editor, it will be reformatted in one line:

```
public TestBankTask(String taskName, String bankCode) { super(taskName, bankCode); }
```

Comment: Please, select the answer as accepted if your question is resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is collapsing one-line methods by default (it's not reformat, but the visual folding only, the file on disk remains the same). You can disable it here:

[image: collapse]

Comment: Perfect answer!!